# Shrink matrix with Eigen using block() in assignment

Tags: c++, eigen

I have following code that shrinks an Eigen MatrixXd by removing the last line. Anyway, that seems to corrupt the matrix. Also valgrind is very upset on that code. What is the proper way to perform that task?

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Eigen::MatrixXd A(3, 4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            A(i, j) = i * j + i + j + 5;
    std::cout << "A = \n" << A << std::endl;

    A = A.block(0, 0, 2, 4);

    std::cout << "A = \n" << A << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code produces the following output on my machine (note 5 became 0)

```
A = 
 5  6  7  8
 6  8 10 12
 7 10 13 16
A = 
 0  6  7  8
 6  8 10 12
```

Comment: I found the proper function `Matrix::conservativeResize`, but I'm still curious what I was doing incorrectly with `block` and how to avoiding such mistakes in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Eigen::Block<...>` (which the `block()` member function returns) does not make a copy of the values involved but acts as a reference to part of the matrix. You can see this with

```
A.block(0, 0, 2, 4) *= 2; // this will change A
```

Because of this, an `Eigen::Block` object remains valid only as long as the underlying matrix does not relocate its values, which it will if you assign something with a different geometry to it (such as `A.block(0, 0, 2, 4)`). Once the underlying matrix has released its pre-assignment memory, using the `Block` object constitutes use-after-free and causes undefined behavior, and the assignment operator will, of course, attempt to read the values from the then-defunct `Block`.

As you have found out yourself in the meantime, you can use

```
A.conservativeResize(2, 4);
```

for your particular case, because you want to shrink towards the upper left corner. For the general case, you can use (for example)

```
A = A.block(1, 1, 2, 3).eval();
```

`.eval()` forces immediate instead of lazy evaluation, which in this case essentially means that a temporary copy of the block is made and then assigned to the matrix. More detail about all this can be found [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicLazyEvaluation.html) in the Eigen documentation.

Comment: I incorrectly supposed that relocation doesn't happen in this particular case